# SimpleMachineForums Login from third party application

Tags: java, authentication, libgdx, smf-forum

So, my issue is that I can't find any information about how SMF (2.0.x) login requests work. I want to have a third party application which would do a test login to make sure the username and password are connected to an user account, so it can then be used with other features of the app. The app is a LibGDX app, which is for PC use. However I do not know how to do a login request to SMF and I dont know what it sends back either. If you know any documentation or know something yourself, please let me know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure out this by using this tutorial: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-automate-login-a-website-java-example